# Is there Thom isomorphism for equivariant K groups in algebraic geometry, not necessarily complex number field?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-k-theory, geometric-representation-theory

In Chriss and Ginzburg's fantastic book 'representation theory and complex geometry', they use the following Thom Isomorphism:

$\pi:E\rightarrow X$, is a G-equivariant affine linear bundle, then $\pi^{*}: K^{G}(X)\rightarrow K^{G}(F)$

It seems that the Thom isomorphism and cellular fibration can provide a lot of information of the equivariant K theory of flag varieties and Steinberg varieties.

In the book, the injectivity of the map is proved by using specialization which seems (for me) to be a topological method

Questions:

(1)Whether there is any algebraic proof of this isomorphism ?

(2)And does this still holds for other algebraically closed field?